# HTML/CSS alinear input radio

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, tengo una duda sobre como puedo alinear verticalmente cada uno de lo inputs radio, ya que al ponerle un LABEL mas largo que otro ocurre lo de la imagen, quisiera que todos los inputs radio empiezen en el mismo sitio (y que por poner una opcion mas larga no se desvarie de esa forma).

Comment: Hola Adrián, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, lee [ask] y edita la pregunta con los consejos que encontrarás allí. Por ejemplo, debes añadir el código a la pregunta (lee cómo crear un [mcve]).

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código que tienes actualmente para que te podamos ayudar mejor con tu problema. Ahora no podemos saber exactamente lo que le puede ocurrir a tu código.

Answer (score 4):

Seguro que habrá mejores soluciones, pero te dejo lo siguiente. Aplicando `text-align` y `padding`:

```css
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<h4>¿Cuál es el ... ?</h4>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="radio" id="val1"
           name="respuesta" value="val1">
    <label for="val1">Opción dsasad</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="val2"
           name="respuesta" value="val2">
    <label for="val2">Opción d</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="val3"
           name="respuesta" value="val3">
    <label for="val3">Opción sadasdsadasd fdfsd</label><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `left` no es un valor válido para la propiedad [`text-justify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify). En tu demo, si quitas esa linea, todo sigue funcionando igual.

Comment: Bien visto. Cuando tenga un momento lo editó. Gracias @Marcos

Answer (score 3):

Como ya muchos te han respondido con formas correctas de resolver tu problema, **yo lo que haré es recomendarte como ampliar la forma en que puedes maquetar el html**, para que quede **más ordenado** y con etiquetas de formulario que casi nadie conoce, pero que son buenas prácticas usarlas para la w3c.

### Mis recomendaciones:

- Trata de que el contenedor principal de todas las preguntas siempre sea la etiqueta **form**.
- Para envolver cada pregunta puedes usar la etiqueta **fieldset**.
- Cada pregunta textual puede estar en un **legend**. Si te das cuenta, sin añadirle estilos extras, estos se combinan con los fieldset de una manera muy estetica y no te preocupes esa "linea" es un border de toda la vida. Si no va con tus estilos, simplemente añádele un "none".
- Y para envolver cada grupo de inputs, un **div**.
- Esto es opcional, pero es una buena forma de mantener orden con cada input e incluso personalizar la forma de este y es envolviendo estos dentro del input. así:

  - **<label> <input /> </label>**
- Relaciona el **ID** del Input con el **FOR** de cada label correspondiente.así:

  - **<label for="val1"> <input id="val1" /> </label>**
- Siempre por accesibilidad, los label deberían de tener **cursor: pointer** asignado.
- Para hacer que cada input esté en un línea diferente, en vez de usar **</br>**, puedes usar **display: block;** en cada **label**.
- Con esta forma de usar las etiquetas html, lograr que se alineen hacia un lado los input (en este caso label), pero que aún este en el centro de la pregunta, se logra simplemente añadiendo al div que agrupa los input:

  - **div { display: inline-block; text-align: left; }**

De esa manera sin importar el tamaño de cada label, estos siempre estaran centrados, pero a su vez alineados.

```css
* { padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; }

body { font-size: 16px; font-family: arial; }

form { text-align: center; }

legend { font-weight: bold; padding: 1em; font-size: 18px;} 

fieldset{ border: solid 1px cyan; padding-bottom: 1em; }

fieldset div{ display: inline-block; text-align: left; }

label { display: block; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="form-question">
      <legend>¿Cuál es el ... ?</legend>
      <div class="group-input ">
        <label for="val1">
          <input type="radio" id="val1" name="respuesta">
          Opción dsasad
        </label>
        <label for="val2">
          <input type="radio" id="val2" name="respuesta">
          Opción d
        </label>
        <label for="val3">
          <input type="radio" id="val3" name="respuesta">
          Opción sadasdsadasd fdfsd
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Éxitos!

Answer (score 2):

El usuario Jose ya te ha dado una solución perfectamente válida, por complementar con otras maneras de hacerlo, te dejo esta forma.

```css
#wrapper{
  display:table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#formulario{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>¿Cuál es el lenguaje estándar específico para aplicar estilos de presentación a nuestra página web ?</p>
  <form id="formulario">
    <input type="radio" id="opcion1" name="opcion" value="opcion1">html
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="opcion2" name="opcion" value="opcion2">css
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="opcion3" name="opcion" value="opcion3">php
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="opcion4" name="opcion" value="opcion4">xml
  </form>
</div>
```