# Alinear inputs radio verticalmente

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy intentando alinear una secuencia de *inputs radios*, pero no soy capaz. Una vez que pongo *align center* no salen alineados verticalmente los botones. Necesito que queden los *inputs* alineados en el centro y verticalmente, junto con el texto. Es para un formulario concreto.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    body {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      height: 100%;
      line-height: 28px;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
      color: #646464;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .test {
      width: 100%;
      color: #5d5d5d;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    input[type='radio'],
    label {
      vertical-align: baseline;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" name="prueba">
    <section>
      <div class="test" style="">
        <input class="a" id="Yo no me he dado de alta" name="P6" type="radio" value="Yo no me he dado de alta" /><label class="">&nbsp; Yo no me he dado de alta</label> <br>

        <input class="inputradio" id="Un familiar está dado de alta" name="P6" type="radio" value="Un familiar está dado de alta" /><label class="motivos">&nbsp; Un familiar está dado de alta</label> <br>


        <input class="inputradio" id="Mi vecino me lo recomendó" name="P6" type="radio" value="Mi vecino me lo recomendó" /><label class="motivos">&nbsp; Mi vecino me lo recomendó</label> <br>

        <input class="inputradio" id="111" name="P6" type="radio" value="Otro motivo" /><label class="motivos">&nbsp; Otro motivo</label>
      </div>
    </section>



  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola tal vez esto podria servirte se usa un container para alinear

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30%;
}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <form method="post" name="prueba">
    <section>
      <div class="test" style="">
        <input class="a" id="Yo no me he dado de alta" name="P6" type="radio" value="Yo no me he dado de alta" /><label class="">&nbsp; Yo no me he dado de alta</label> <br>

        <input class="inputradio" id="Un familiar está dado de alta" name="P6" type="radio" value="Un familiar está dado de alta" /><label class="motivos">&nbsp; Un familiar está dado de alta</label> <br>


        <input class="inputradio" id="Mi vecino me lo recomendó" name="P6" type="radio" value="Mi vecino me lo recomendó" /><label class="motivos">&nbsp; Mi vecino me lo recomendó</label> <br>

        <input class="inputradio" id="111" name="P6" type="radio" value="Otro motivo" /><label class="motivos">&nbsp; Otro motivo</label>
      </div>
    </section>



  </form>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Me base de la siguiente respuesta.

[HTML/CSS alinear input radio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128181/html-css-alinear-input-radio/128192)

Comment: muchas gracias!